# from INT to time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm out of ideas here.

In my DB table, I have all sorts of entries and they all have a row with `start_time` and `duration`. In this situation, the only way I could've entered the values was:

10:00 is entered in the db as 1000, and 23:00 is entered as 2300.

The durations are 130 for 1 and a half hours or 20 for twenty  minutes and so on.

They are entered just as you would expect them to be without any symbols separating the digits. 
The problem is, I just can't add the numbers and need to get the `end_time` calculated by adding the two values.

As an example, If i have an event starting at 1045 and it lasts 45 , I just need to echo 1130.

Comment: If it is 9 AM, would it be entered as 0900?

Comment: @AJ yes, or 900, changing that is the easy part, right now it is 900 but I'll gladly change it to 0900 if someone can help

Comment: Are you not able to change the data types of the database? If so it would be the correct approach since later, it will ease your date / time related calculations.

Comment: @CiprianKis Added an answer. Check if this helps.

Comment: @AJ it worked perfect as soon as I changed from "900" to "0900" , Thank You!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'll gladly change it to 0900

You can try following:

```
$timed = strtotime("+".$duration." minutes", strtotime($time));
echo date('Hi', $timed);
```

First you need to convert the time and add your duration. After that, you can echo it as desired.

For eg.

```
 $timed = strtotime("+130 minutes", strtotime("0900"));
 echo date('Hi', $timed);
```

It will output

> 1110